# Find all crtical node sets in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a graph , I want to find the sets S1, S2, ... of nodes whose removal may disconnect the network. Each of these sets may contain a single node or more.
Also any of these sets are not subsets of each other i.e. we do not consider S3=S1 U S2 though it also disconnects the network.

We **don't** want to find :

1. Only one critical node set but all
2. The single set of nodes that disconnect the network to a maximum extent.

Any suggestions on any of these:

1. Hardness of the problem
2. Some direction/paper reference to the solution
3. Any proofs that I may have to give

Answer (score 1):

Vertex sets whose removal disconnects a graph are called separators. See e.g. A. Berry,  J-P Bordat, O. Cogis: [Generating all the Minimal Separators of a Graph](http://www.isima.fr/~berry/generating.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to find is [graph partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partitioning_problem).
It is a [**NP Hard**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem.
See [this](http://www.stanford.edu/group/mmds/slides/spielman-mmds.pdf) for more understanding of graph partitioning. there are [Nearly-Linear Time Algorithms for Graph Partitioning](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Nearly-Linear%20Time%20Algorithms%20for%20Graph%20Partitioning&oq=Nearly-Linear%20Time%20Algorithms%20for%20Graph%20Partitioning) available if you google for it.

Comment: Please leave a comment if there are any issues. And if you found the answer correct/helpful, accept it.